# В чем интерес быть модератором?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, выборы

Почему некоторые участники стремятся стать модераторами? В чем здесь интерес? Что ими движет?

Как по мне, то бывало, расстраивался, что потерял какой-нибудь час на СО, когда мог бы потратить его на более насущные вещи. Да, конечно, пользы много, когда чего-то не знаешь и тебе подсказывают. Но если взять модератора, то у него работа, наверное, другие дела... И при этом надо почти что постоянно следить за сайтом.

Наверное, не до конца понимаю, как СО работает, поэтому и  не понимаю и этот момент.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Сама идея SO - добровольная помощь и организация знаний.

> Как по мне, то бывало, что расстраивался, что потерял какой-нибудь час
>   на СО, когда мог бы потратить его на более насущные вещи.

Я, к примеру, не рассматриваю время проведённое на SO, как "потраченное". Чем больше мы сделаем для SO, тем больше сэкономим время людей в будущем.

> Да, конечно, пользы много, когда чего-то не знаешь и тебе
>   подсказывают. Но если взять модератора, то у него работа, наверное,
>   другие дела... и при этом надо почти что постоянно следить за сайтом.

Статус модератора просто даёт дополнительные инструменты, с помощью которых человек может сделать SO ещё лучше. Да и никто не заставляет просиживать целыми днями на SO.

Comment: Зеленую галочку этому господину! ))

Comment: А если без лицемерия? Идея SO - эксплуатация чужих знаний и организация толпы путем воздействия на чувство тщеславия раздачей иллюзорных баллов. Модератор в этой системе получает ощущение власти, затем и идет. А что нужно создателям ресурса? Манипулировать мнением профессионального сословия программистов, направляя его в нужную сторону. Мне сложно представить, кто из взрослых людей поверит в ваши вышеприведенные 4 абзаца.

Comment: @Eugene вы в каждой теме теперь будете свою желчь выплёскивать?

Comment: @Eugene `Идея SO - эксплуатация чужих знаний и организация толпы путем воздействия на чувство тщеславия раздачей иллюзорных баллов` — это у кармадрочеров, которых, не спорю, достаточно много. У других же репутация чешется до трёх тысяч, на которых открывается весь инструментарий для полноценного участия (хотя кто-то и до десяти тянет, чтобы видеть удалённые вопросы). Ну а дальше люди отвечают из того расчёта, что свободного времени много, а вопрос интересный и достаточно граблесобирающий. То есть всё чисто по фану.

Answer (score 2):

> Почему некоторые участники стремятся стать модераторами? В чем здесь интерес? Что ими движет?

На мой взгляд разными людьми движет разная сила... Для некоторых, как кто-то заметил в комментариях, это способ самоутверждения, для других возможность "сделать этот мир лучше", но в любом случае, у каждого свои, только ему известные, "движители"...

Также соглашусь с Вами в том, что для качественного модерирования необходимо уделять много времени, которое не у всех имеется, ну и рабочую дисциплину никто не отменял...

Если резюмировать, то имеется работа, которую кто-то должен делать. Местами эта работа не благодарная, вызывающая много критики, но от этого никуда не деться...

Answer (score -15):

Почувствовать неограниченную ВЛАСТЬ над людьми - вот основной интерес.

Если что, к знаниям стремятся тоже ради власти (по крайней мере так Бекон считал), а модератору достаточно кнопочку нажать, и изобретать ничего не надо.

Comment: Модератор на SO — это не царь и бог, а завхоз, который должен разгребать конфликты и экстренно реагировать на призывы по тревогам. С вашим же подходом вас быстро уберут из модераторов — тут и без самоутверждения работы выше крыши, чтобы разбираться с самоуправством кого-то из новоизбранных.

Comment: Не спорю, в начале понять это трудно. Но побывав здесь пару-тройку лет и активно откомментировав и поответив на вопросы, поразбирав очереди тревог (на 500 баллах репутации открывается тонюсенький ручеёк, на 3000 вываливается весь поток, на 10 000 обрушивается Ниагарский водопад), поучаствовав в драмах, выслушав в свой адрес неадекватностей и оскорблений (к счастью, вы не такой, но был тут один упоротый java-адепт...), начинаешь относиться ко всему этому пофигистически.

Comment: Мол, нафига нужна власть, сопряжённая со знатным геморроем, если и в ранге высокоуровневого участника (модератора на минималках) «развлечений» выше крыши.

Comment: И в этом, кстати, преимущество стека над форумами — сама организация сайта, *требующая* активного общения с огромным количеством разных людей, и долгий карьерный рост через репутацию вплоть до мини-модератора (10k) и только потом уже до полноценного модератора душат комплекс вахтёра на корню.

Comment: Преимущество для кого? Может быть для владельца данного ресурса. Для всех остальных - нет. Система рейтинга вообще зло, система глобального рейтинга - большое зло. Конечно, рейтинг это как пучок зелени перед ослом - заставляет бесплодно бежать вперед, делая работу бесплатно в погоне за пустым тщеславием. Поднимаются наверх при такой системе не знающие технари, а умеющие манипулировать толпой гуманитарии со слабыми техническими знаниями. И я предполагаю и даже уверен, что тут есть люди, которым платят деньги за рекламу и агитацию (например за рекламу продукции гугла).

Comment: Такая профессия давно известна и их не волнует истина, зато они обучены манипулировать глупыми и невеждами и натравливать их на знающих "умников". "Умники" для таких людей вообще враги, так как мешают зарабатывать деньги.

Comment: Самый лучший случай - когда каждый "модерирует" свой собственный сайт. Система форумов была намного лучше, чем глобальный стекофефлоу, там и рейтинга не было, и можно было пойти на другой форум. А здесь как мегакорпорация или социалистическое государство. Уже и тупые боты стали людям указывать что им делать - верх неуважения.

Comment: ну так займитесь *модерацией*: Получите привилегию для доступа к очереди проверок, поработайте с ней. Улучшите вопросы задаваемые *новичками*. Если Вы крутой специалист, то отвечайте на вопросы. Внесите посильный вклад в улучшение. *можно было пойти на другой форум* - а что изменилось? Вас под пытками заставляют писать вопросы/ответы/комментарии

Comment: `Система рейтинга вообще зло, система глобального рейтинга — большое зло.` — к сожалению, пока что это единственное средство обеспечения меритократии (власти достойных, заслуживших). Только с повышением рейтинга открываются возможности по модерированию сайта, поэтому для его заработка приходится задавать хорошие вопросы и давать исчерпывающие ответы (а иначе рейтинг не заработать чисто технически; в базу данных тоже залезть не получится — к ней есть доступ только у высших эшелонов американской компании, которой принадлежит стек).

Comment: Просто так, за красивые глаза, развесистый язык и связи с модератором тут никто ничего не даст даже при всём желании, ибо сайт так устроен (в отличие от тех же форумов, где такая ерунда более чем возможна).

Comment: `Конечно, рейтинг это как пучок зелени перед ослом — заставляет бесплодно бежать вперед, делая работу бесплатно в погоне за пустым тщеславием.` — никто не заставляет набирать максимальный рейтинг или вообще хоть как-то его набирать. Если вам неинтересна модерация, можете потихоньку задавать необходимые вам вопросы, не давая ответов и вообще не заморачиваясь с репутацией — тревоги модератору можно кидать и с нулями баллов. Ну будет он сам по себе капать медленными темпами, и что?

Comment: `Поднимаются наверх при такой системе не знающие технари, а умеющие манипулировать толпой гуманитарии со слабыми техническими знаниями.` — чтобы стать модератором, надо не только крутиться на Мете, но и заработать минимум десять тысяч баллов (это тысяча плюсов за ответы или пять тысяч плюсов за вопросы без учёта минусов), и активно разгребать очереди на закрытие/переоткрытие/правки. Согласен, на Мете манипулятор действительно чувствует себя как рыба в воде, но с остальным у него терпения не хватит доползти до заветного рубежа.

Comment: `И я предполагаю и даже уверен, что тут есть люди, которым платят деньги за рекламу и агитацию (например за рекламу продукции гугла)` — а при чём здесь гугл и (предвыборная?) агитация? Оплату всё равно получает американский офис (мы — всего лишь один из 174 сайтов в рамках американского Stack Exchange, https://stackexchange.com), так что единственный, кто здесь впринципе получает деньги — это Николас Чабановский, сотрудник, управляющий сообществом.

Comment: И то, в отличие от форумного администратора, он здесь далеко не бог, над ним стоят более серьёзные люди, легко доступные через https://meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: `"Умники" для таких людей вообще враги, так как мешают зарабатывать деньги` — мы всё ещё о выборах в модераторы говорим (тема вопроса, на который вы написали исходный ответ)? И как «умники» могут мешать, если именно они создают наполнение сайта, за которым и приходят посетители, приносящие компании доход?

Comment: `Самый лучший случай — когда каждый «модерирует» свой собственный сайт.` — на уровне личного сайта можно потянуть максимум блог с комментариями; с таким подходом до стекового удобства и количества специалистов в ответах как до Китая раком.

Comment: `Система форумов была намного лучше, чем глобальный стекофефлоу, там и рейтинга не было` — зато были лычки («дух», «новичок», «ветеран»). Вот только на форумах это ни на что не влияющие пузомерки. На рейтинге же стека завязана вся механика по постепенному раскрытию доступных возможностей, то есть тут уже реальная необходимость в его наборе.

Comment: `и можно было пойти на другой форум` — во-первых, «StackOverlow на русском» — это, повторюсь, лишь один из 174 сайтов «сети StackExchange», так что здесь тоже можно «пойти на другой форум» (полный список — на https://stackexchange.com/sites). Во-вторых, это уже не говоря о других сайтах вопросов-ответов с той же механикой (мэйл.ру, тостер и прочие неизвестные мне). Так что даже в рамках одной механики выбор тем и сообществ огромен.

Comment: `здесь как мегакорпорация или социалистическое государство. Уже и тупые боты стали людям указывать что им делать — верх неуважения.` — если вопросы и ответы — это активы, то да, один только русский стек — уже мегакорпорация. Вот только и масштабы оборотов здесь тоже как у корпорации, и вручную всё это при всём желании не отследить. Не знаю, можете ли вы видеть свои удалённые вопросы, но в «Что тут за боты существуют» (https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8986) я успел дать комментарии с описанием масштабов того, что здесь приходится автоматизировать.

Comment: Нет, конечно, мы готовы отказаться от ботов, оскорбляющих одним фактом своего существования, вот только кому-то придётся делать всю работу за них. Согласны стать добровольцем? https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMZY9.png